# How do I find the highest height in this Mechanics/Suvat question?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, classical-mechanics

I've found the speed of Q when P hits the ground already; its 4.43. I've tried using that information to find the height, and I get 2M, when the answer is 3m. I think I'm going about this the wrong way, can someone help?

[image]

Comment: What is Suvat  ?

Comment: Could you answer me ?

Comment: @JeanMarie SUVAT is a mnemonic for identifying which velocity/acceleration formula you should use. S = DiSplacement. U = Initial Velocity. V = Final Velocity. A= Acceleration. T= Time.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't imagine at all it was about that.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be 2m as Q is at 2m already when P hits the ground.  Q is moving upward at that time.  You need to compute how far Q rises against gravity when starting at 4.43 m/sec upward.

Comment: How am I meant to solve it without V though?

Comment: You have V.  It is the 4.43 you already calculated.  You can compute the height just be energy balance.  We haven't come to the part where they say without further calculation.